# Show that $A_n(x)\to 0$ for $x\in \bar U=\{y-T(y)|y\in H\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T:H\to H$ is an isometric linear map.
Let  $U=\{y-T(y)|y\in H\}$. Then, show that for any $x\in \bar U$

$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}(x+T(x)+...+T^{n-1}(x))\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

My attempt: Let $x\in \bar U$. Suppose $x_m=y_m-T(y_m)\in U$ are such that $x_m\to x$. Then,
$P_n(x_m) = \frac{1}{n}(y_m-T(y_m)+...+T^{n-1}(y_m)-T^n(y_m))
=\frac{1}{n}(y_m-T^n(y_m))$. If, somehow, we are able to show that $|y_m-T^n(y_m)|<M$ for some $M>0$.

Then,
$|P_n(x_m)| =|\frac{1}{n}(y_m-T^n(y_m))|<\frac{1}{n}\cdot M\to0$.
But, I am not sure how to show the boundedness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\|T\|=1$ and the triangle inequality.

Regarding the whole calculation....

This is a classic computation in ergodic theory. Let $x\in U$. Then $x=y-Ty$ and 
$$nP_nx=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}T^lx=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}T^ly-\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}T^{l+1}y=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}T^ly-\sum_{l=1}^{n}T^{l}y=y-T^ny.$$
Therefore, 
$$\|P_nx\|=\frac{\|y-T^ny\|}{n}\leq \frac{\|y\|+\|T^ny\|}{n}\leq \frac{2\|y\|}{n}\rightarrow 0.$$

Let $z\in \overline{U}$. $U$ is dense in $\overline{U}$, so for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x\in U$ such that $\|x-y\|<\epsilon$. But 
$$\Big|\|P_nx\|-\|P_ny\|\Big|\leq \|P_n(x-y)\|\leq \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\|T^k(x-y)\|}{n}\leq \epsilon$$
Performing the $n\rightarrow \infty$ limit,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\|P_nx\|\leq \epsilon$$
for all $\epsilon>0$.

See Yosida, K.: Mean ergodic theorem in Banach spaces

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195579607